# Android AlarmManager run every day 3 pm

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I searched but didn't really find something. Just some examples for running AM every 20 seconds after hit a button etc.
I want that on the first start of my app an AM is started which runs every day at 3 pm and checks some things. It should be possible that the AM is running everyday even if the app doesn't start for 2-3 days.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: No, because I don't know how/where I have to start the AM that it just starts at the first time and not every time I open the app. (because after the first time, it should run already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #1: Create a `Calendar` object that represents 3pm tomorrow. Make sure that it is *tomorrow*, as if it is after 3pm today, just saying "3pm" will give you a time in the past.

Step #2: Use that with `AlarmManager`. Use `setRepeating()` for Android 4.3 and below. For Android 4.4 and above, doing something at a precise time is frowned upon, and so you will probably wind up calling `setExact()` to get control once, then in that code call `setExact()` again to schedule the next event.

Step #3: If you want to wake up the device when these events occur, use `RTC_WAKEUP` for the alarm type, and tie it to either a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` or a regular `BroadcastReceiver` that uses [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

Comment: I created a Calendar like this: `  Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,19);
     cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,8);
     cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);` to test it out, but it doesn't do anything at this time. Is it right in this way? The other stuff should be right, I read a tutorial. Just this Calendar I tried myself.

Comment: @Phil: "Is it right in this way?" -- only if the local time is before 19:08. Otherwise, that time is in the past, and you need to add a day. You can use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to see all the scheduled `AlarmManager` events.

Comment: @Phil: The same place you run any other command-line program on your development OS. For example, on Linux or OS X, it would be in a terminal window. If the `adb` binary is not in your `PATH`, you can add it, or simply run the command from the `platform-tools/` directory of your SDK installation.